# Windows terminals interleave escape sequences

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, windows-terminal

I am writing a cross-platform interactive terminal program that receives cursor query responses and mouse events. (The cursor query is actually to detect window size change, since Window Ops are typically disabled.) It works fine in Linux terminals, but in Windows terminals I get interleaved event sequences such as:

```
\x1b\x1b[46;128R[<32;54;17M
```

This happens in both `PowerShell` and `cmd.exe`. The interleaved sequences always seem to start with `\x1b\x1b` but I don't find that very reassuring. I can reduce the occurrence of interleaving by turning off mouse events, waiting a delay, querying the cursor, waiting another delay, and turning the mouse events back on. But this makes the program less responsive, and still doesn't eliminate all the occurrences.

How can I deal with these interleaved sequences? Can I get Windows to not interleave? Or is there a standard way I'm supposed to parse the interleaved sequnces? (Where is this documented?)

**Reproducing**

Run the following script under `wsl` in a `PowerShell` or `cmd.exe`. Then jiggle the mouse for a few seconds.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import sys, os, tty, re, time, select

Enable_Mouse_Events  = "\x1b[?1003h\x1b[?1006h"
Disable_Mouse_Events = "\x1b[?1006l\x1b[?1003l"
Get_Window_Size      = "\x1b[s\x1b[999;999H\x1b[6n\x1b[u"

fd         = sys.stdin.fileno()
buf        = bytearray()
query_time = Immediately = 0
fail_time  = Never       = 9e9

def Print(x, end = '\r\n'):
    sys.stdout.write(x + end)
    sys.stdout.flush()

def Exit(msg):
    Print(Disable_Mouse_Events, '')
    Print(msg)
    time.sleep(0.05)
    while select.select([fd,], [], [], 0)[0]:
        os.read(fd, 4096)
    os._exit(0)

tty.setraw(fd)
Print(Enable_Mouse_Events, '')
while True:

    # mouse event?
    m = re.match(r'\x1b\[\<(\d*);(\d*);(\d*)([Mm])', buf)
    if m:
        b, x, y, s = (bytes(s) for s in m.groups())
        Print("mouse: b=%s, x=%s, y=%s, s=%s" % (b, x, y, s))
        del buf[:len(m.group(0))]
        fail_time = Never
        continue
        
    # response to cursor query?
    m = re.match(r'\x1b\[(\d*);(\d*)R', buf)
    if m:
        y, x = (bytes(s) for s in m.groups())
        Print("window size: x=%s, y=%s" % (x, y))
        del buf[:len(m.group(0))]
        fail_time = Never
        continue

    # check for more data
    timeout = max(0, min(query_time, fail_time) - time.time())
    if not select.select([fd,], [], [], timeout)[0]:
        Print(Get_Window_Size, '')
        query_time = time.time() + 0.1
        if time.time() > fail_time:
            Exit('Parsing timed out! buf = %s' % repr(bytes(buf)))
        continue

    # got more data
    buf.extend(os.read(fd, 4096))
    if '\x03' in buf:
        Exit('^C')

    # Set a timeout if not already set and there is more data.
    if buf and fail_time is Never:
        fail_time = time.time() + 1
```

Comment: What api / library are you receiving these events with? Can you show enough code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @mclayton I'm using the python2 `re` interface. I've added example code for reproducing.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect, it's a problem of the "\x1b[6n".
See the difference between linux/windows

Tested with the sequence `\x1b[1;1H\x1b[6n\x1b[7;7H\x1b[6n`
First it sets the cursor to 1,1 then it request the cursor position,
then set the cursor to 7,7 and request the cursor position again.

On Linux the response is:
`\x1b[1;1R\x1b[7;7R`

On Windows the response is:
`\x1b[7;7R\x1b[1;1R`

Linux just appends the answers for queries to the end of the input buffer,
but Windows put the answers (like `\x1b[6n` and `\x1b[0c` ) to the front of the input buffer!

This seems to be wrong or at least not very wise.
And it seems that in some situations it might fail if another sequence is to be inserted, like your mouse position.
When a mouse position is to be inserted, it seems possible that the report cursor position answer can interrupt the message, but instead of simple inserting at the front it starts at position 1.

A solution should be possible by checking for two ESC, when the second escape starts a valid sequence of `ESC[x;yR` then assume you got already the ESC for the next sequence.

Comment: Good detective work! So it seems that something is going on with the cursor response ordering in Windows. For my application, where I only need one query outstanding, your solution of checking for two ESC and saving the first one for later appears to work reliably. But how do we know that the interleaving always happens this way? Why couldn't we get, say, `\x1b[\x1b[`...? (At which point we can't distinguish the digits from the two sequences.)